# How to exclude the first element of an enumerated Type used as an array index in delphi?

Tags: delphi

I want to exclude the first value of this enumerated type

```
type
  TEnum = (val0, val1, val2, val3, val4);
```

in order to make this array

```
TBValues: array [low(TEnum)..High(TEnum)] of boolean;
```

contains only the last n-1 values (in this case n=5).

I tried this:

```
TBValues: array [low(TEnum)+1..High(TEnum)] of boolean;
```

but I guess arithmetic operations are not allowed in this case because I'm getting this compiler error

> E2010 Incompatible types: 'Int64' and 'TEnum'

How to do this?

Comment: Strange compiler message. `TBValues = array [Ord(Low(TEnum)) ..High(TEnum)] of Boolean;` this also complains of an Int64 incompatibility.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I had the same question in my mind but I found the solution. this is what the documentation says about Ord(X): _X is a Delphi ordinal-type expression. The result is the ordinal position of X; **its type is the smallest standard integer type that can hold all values of X's type.**_ Hence the error message.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What about the obvious:

```
TBValues: array [val1..val4] of boolean;
```

If you want to avoid the actual enum names, you can write it this way:

```
TBValues: array [Succ(low(TEnum))..High(TEnum)] of boolean;
```

For more information:

- [Succ](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Succ)
- [Pred](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Pred)

Comment: I really like your second option. The whole point to me is to avoid enum names